# CountA function for a specific value in an external workbook

Tags: excel-formula

i am looking to count how many Product 1 is in the specified range on a different workbook. currently what i have is this.

=counta('path[file.xlsx]sheet!E2:E301,"Product 1")-1

It only returns me the filled range which is 300. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

COUNTA counts all cells in range that are not empty and its only argument is a range that should be checked,so you'll either have to create a helper column with a formula that will return blank cell if the record is not Product 1 or use  COUNTIF(range,criteria) but you'll need to open both workbooks to update the values.

Comment: =count(if('path[file.xlsx]sheet!E2:E301,"Product 1")-1)

i did tried this, returned 0.

Comment: No the function's name is COUNTIF, you don't need to combine Count and If

Comment: `=COUNTIF('path[file.xlsx]sheet!E2:E301,"Product 1")` I don't really understand what is the minus 1 for

Comment: You need to allow excel to update values from closed workbooks when you start it. Try to input the formula while both workbooks are open, then see what happens when you reopen the target workbook alone.

Comment: it does extract the number of product 1 when the workbook is open. but it doesn't return value when closed.

Comment: I'll add more details if the first part is hard to understand.